# Hibernate automatically updating Entity1 when querying Entity2

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm not expecting a concrete answer for this question because it's way too complex to explain in detail, just some guidance on where the problem could be.

Im summary, I have an entity Ship, with foreign keys to entities Origin, Destination and Country. I fetch a Ship from the database, then modify other field (date), and then query the database for related Origin, Destination and Country. When I query for Origin and Country, it goes as expected, but when I query for Destination, when executing `query.getResultList()` , and before the `select a from DESTINATION`, Hibernate automatically executes `update SHIP set ...`  and it sets all the Ship fields except for IDN_DEST.

Any idea of what could this be happening?

My guess is that since the entity has been modified within the Session, Hibernates somehow things it needs to be updated, but that's all.

For what I've seen, there are no differences in the Ship.java:

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "IDN_ORIGIN", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Origin tOrigin;

@Column(name = "IDN_ORIGIN")
private Integer idnOrigin;

// bi-directional many-to-one association
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "IDN_DEST", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Destination tDest;

@Column(name = "IDN_DEST", updatable = false)
private Integer idnDest;

// bi-directional many-to-one association
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "IDN_COUNTRY", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Country tCountry;

@Column(name = "IDN_COUNTRY")
private Integer idnCountry;
```

Comment: Provide your code,please

Comment: There is really too much of it, it's impossible to paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

About your question: Hibernate before a `Query.list()` perform a dirty check and automatically do a `flush()` to prevent inconsistent state.
To prevent that change `Session.flushMode` to COMMIT if you don't want automatic flush, but only at commit time. 
About your example, two things:

- Why you are not using a getter to get `tOrigin, tCountry, tDest`?
- May you read `tOrigin, tCountry, tDest` before `Ship` update?

Answer (score 0):

Tis is happening because when you select a `Destination` hibernate auto-flushes the session, so the state of the `Ship` is updated in the database. This means that when you *modify other field (date)* the ship object is attached to the session.

Comment: That's what I thought, but why doesn't it happen with `Origin` and `Country`?

Answer (score 0):

That should be not done only with `Destination` as tibtof told when you fetch data from database it creates persistent object and when you modify it hibernate will update it in database when it flushes connection, what you can try is after fetching `Origin` or `Country`  flush session manually you should get updated data as what happened with 'Destination'.